# Aligning HTML elements horizontally

Tags: html, alignment

How to align these elements next to each others and not below each others?

```
<form action="http://xx.xxx.com/checker.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="tokenz" value="9oaisdkjasiduqasdkjiwue" />
<input type="hidden" name="directz" value="true" />
Domain: <input type="text" name="domain" size="20" /> <select name="ext">
<option>.com</option>
<option>.org</option>
<option>.net</option>
<option>.biz</option>
<option>.info</option>
<option>.us</option>
<option>.pw</option>
<option>.in</option>
<option>.name</option>
<option>.mobi</option>
<option>.asia</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can float the elements to left with 'float: left;'

Comment: Applying `float` does not prevent elements from wrapping.

Answer (score 2):

The form contains inline elements only. This means they will all remain on the same line, until they wrap.

If you want to prevent wrapping, try `white-space: nowrap` and give the container a width.

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ballcheck/XbzdK/

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://xx.xxx.com/checker.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="tokenz" value="9oaisdkjasiduqasdkjiwue" />
<input type="hidden" name="directz" value="true" />
Domain: <input type="text" name="domain" size="20" /> <select name="ext">
<option>.com</option>
<option>.org</option>
<option>.net</option>
<option>.biz</option>
<option>.info</option>
<option>.us</option>
<option>.pw</option>
<option>.in</option>
<option>.name</option>
<option>.mobi</option>
<option>.asia</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: i tried to add the class="form" to the form element with no success, they still appear below each others. and i also tried to wrap all teh above in a div with no success.

Comment: @xploit - `form {}` applies to all form elements. There is no need to add a "form" class. Have you seen the working example? http://jsfiddle.net/Ballcheck/XbzdK/

Comment: well, i have to add a class because i have other styles in the page. this is inside a wordpress theme.

Comment: @xploit - Please can you confirm whether or not the working example is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes the working example is what i am trying to achieve. but it does not work in my wordpress page. i think the problem is that the page auto-inserts a <br/> before the <select> tag !!!

Comment: @xploit - Firstly, check with firebug to make sure. You could hide the `<br/>` with `br { display: none }` but that is obviously a hack. Far better to find out why this is happening and fix the root of the problem. If you could supply the _real_ html in a fiddle, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example if that is what you ment:

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/fhbha/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="reg-lists" >
    <li class="one">
        <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
    <li class="two">
            <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
    <li class="three">
            <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
 li {
    display:inline !important;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 10px;    
}
```